# Calculate the diameter of an `sf` object

Tags: sf

The [diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter#Generalizations) of a set of points in a metric space is defined as the supremum of all pairwise distances between points in the set. So in the case of the earth's surface, the diameter of a (closed) set of points is equal to the diameter of the smallest circle that encloses the whole set.

Given an arbitrary `sf` object, such as a `MULTIPOLYGON`, how can I compute the diameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `lwgeom::st_minimum_bounding_circle` can be used to calculate the smallest bounding circle. For example:

```r
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)

# Sample data
set.seed(1)
n = 100
x = data.frame(
  x = (runif(n) * 2 - 1) * 70,
  y = (runif(n) * 2 - 1) * 70
)
x = st_as_sf(x, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = NA)
x = st_union(x)
x = st_convex_hull(x)

# Smallest bounding circle
pol = st_minimum_bounding_circle(x)

# Plot
plot(pol, border = "red")
plot(x, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Since we know that `pol` is a circle, the diameter should be equal to the width (or height) of the bounding box:

```r
# Diameter
diff(st_bbox(pol)[c("xmin","xmax")])
```

```
##     xmax 
## 172.9828
```